# MagicalRecord saveWithBlock completion usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord-2.2

I'm using the `[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock: completion:]` method but I'm not sure how to access the saved object on the completion block. My code is the following

```
NSLog(@"saving player");
__block PSPlayer *player;
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    // parse json
    player = [self parsePlayer:playerInfoJson inContext:localContext];
    NSLog(@"player.md5Id %@", player.md5Id);

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"player.md5Id in success %@ error %@", player.md5Id, error);
    ...
}];
```

The `player.md5Id` is correctly set at the end of the save block but is nil in the completion one. Is this a correct usage?

cheers,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion block captures the `player` reference before it's set so it will be nil when that block gets executed.

If you want to use the new managed object later you should store it in a property and then call a method from the completion block, (possibly switching to the main thread, not sure if MR does that for you) to find that object in the main context.

Alternatively I think you could define the completion block earlier and then pass a `copy` to the method, then the copy would have access to the updated `player` reference (I don't do that very often really but IIRC it should work).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up re-quering my `player` object in the completion block